# How to create a local variable in a html template in django project?

Tags: python, django, html

I am a beginner to python and django.
Here I am trying to build a website.

I have created a class named cluster which actually mean a town or city.
As a subclass I have created schools for cluster.
Schools have a field `school_strength` to get strength for each school.
Now I have to display the total strength of all the schools that belong to each cluster.

This is how I am trying to do that in html template for cluster details by creating a local variable strength to calculate sum from all schools.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="{% url 'music:cluster_detail' state.id region.id cluster.id %}">
                    {% if cluster.cluster_logo %}
                        <img src="{{ cluster.cluster_logo.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                    {% else %}
                        <h3>No image to display</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
                <h2>{{ cluster.cluster_name }}</h2>
                <h4>{{ cluster.cluster_coordinator }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ cluster.cco_number }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ cluster.cco_email }}</h4>
                {% for school in cluster.school_set.all %}
                    {% strength = strength + school.school_strength %}
                {% endfor %}
                <h4>{{ strength }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: any particular reason to calculate this in the template, and not python code?

Comment: You can't use a variable in the template. You should make template tag that will make this logic for you. But, a better way is to make it use a code in `view.py` or use `ModelManager`

Comment: No particular reason. Can you explain me how can I declare a variable and use it in my view.py. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can declare the variable with `with` tag. But that **will not work the the way you want it to work**. Below is an example to it.

```
{% with name="World" greeting="Hello" %}     
    <h1>{{ greeting }} {{name}}!</h1>
{% endwith %}
```

So, the better way is you can store it in a variable in `views.py` and pass it to html template.

**views.py**

```
strength=0
for school in cluster.school_set.all():
     strength = strength + school.school_strength

context['strength']=strength

return render(request, 'template/html`, context)
```

**html**

```
<h3>Strength Of Cluster: {{strength}}</h3>
```

Comment: That really helped. Thank you.

Comment: cluster.school_set.all():

Comment: Thats really nice of you.Feel privileged to help you out.  If you think this solution helped you , you can select this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that it's not the template. I updated the answer. Thanks